# Is Wikipedia <math> on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Tex.sx has a tag for questions that is named [`wiki`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki) and currently has this description:

> Topics linked to usage of TeX in wiki-type websites, such as Wikipedia.

Wikipedia (run by Wikimedia, running on Mediawiki software) has long been using mathmode syntax inside [`<math>` elements](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math) for generating formulas in articles. The exact way this has been parsed (client-/server-side MathJax, OCaml [texvc](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/EMAT/browse/REL1_23/texvccheck/README), [texvcjs](https://github.com/wikimedia/texvcjs), Mathoid) and displayed (source code, MathML, PNG, SVG) has differed over time and may depend on browser capabilities and user settings. 
However, it basically supports all of plain LaTeX plus AMSmath.

Since a [question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528274/same-height-for-matrices-regardless-of-fractions-inside) about this particular flavor was closed as off-topic: are questions about the MW/WM Tex dialect [on topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I think it depends... Note that Mathjax is _also_ off-topic here, so all the same observations would apply (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148955/383578). If it's something about the LaTeX syntax that applies to LaTeX as well, then I think it's okay to ask in the context of using it in Wikipedia. But something like (example) "why does this work in LaTeX but not on Wikipedia" is definitely off-topic. Though asking is free, so I'd say: go for it

Comment: Huh, I thought MathJax *syntax* would obviously be on topic as well.

Comment: @Crissov -- Where MathJax syntax conflicts with that of LaTeX, questions about *that* are off-topic.

Comment: One thing to have in mind is: Mathjax (and similars) is _not_ LaTeX, just an emulation of the syntax and the result (if you want to check, try [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474872/134574) and if it runs, it is LaTeX). This distinction makes some Mathjax/wiki-math questions off-topic: solutions will be restricted to what's implemented in the emulation (as you saw in Mico's answer to your question). But usually people here are quite tolerant and will answer your question nevertheless. Also note that the existence of a tag doesn't mean much: anyone can create any tag.

Comment: When it doesn't support `\vphantom` it doesn't support all of plain LaTeX (looking at your earlier question).